# how to check the same value in array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array where days are the key and timings are the values:

```
Array(

    [Mon] => 9:00-10:00,12:00-15:00,10:00-14:00

    [Tue] => 9:00-10:00,12:00-15:00

    [Wed] => 9:00-10:00,12:00-15:00

    [Thu] => 9:00-10:00,12:00-15:00

    [Fri] => 9:00-10:00,12:00-15:00

    [Sat] => 9:00-10:00,12:00-15:00

    [Sun] => 10:00-14:00

)
```

And I want same array in this way:

```
 Array(

    [Mon] => 9:00-10:00,12:00-15:00,10:00-14:00

    [Tue/Wed/Thu/Fri/Sat] => 9:00-10:00,12:00-15:00

    [Sun] => 10:00-14:00

)
```

any one can help me on this?

Comment: http://php.net/array_unique / http://php.net/array_keys / http://php.net/array_count_values - please take a look into the manual  first. Also please make yourself comfortable with the editing tools on this website. The spaces in front are used for - code formatting.

Comment: No, you should first help yourself and try to code it. If your code does not work we will be very happy to help you..

Comment: What is `9:00-10:00,12:00-15:00,10:00-14:00` in `Mon`? A string? An array?

Comment: @Pee - unable to save the same keys in one key for a same value

Comment: @ihsan - i have tried from my end, am not getting the result, so i posted here dear

Comment: @Jueecy  - all values are string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$temp = array();
foreach ($array as $day => $value) {
    if (!in_array($value, $temp)) {
        $temp[] = $value;
        $result[implode("/",array_keys($array,$value))] = $value;
    }
}
```

See [DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/R6p8nE).

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way to achieve this, but the following should work:-

```
$input = <YOUR ARRAY>
$output = array();

foreach ($input as $k => $v) {
  if (!isset($output[$v])) {
    $output[$v] = $k;
  } else {
    $output[$v] .= '/' . $k;
  }
}

print_r(array_flip($output));
```

#### [Here's a working example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/h1SSSO)

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
    'Mon' => '9:00-10:00,12:00-15:00,10:00-14:00',
    'Tue' => '9:00-10:00,12:00-15:00',
    'Wed' => '9:00-10:00,12:00-15:00',
    'Thu' => '9:00-10:00,12:00-15:00',
    'Fri' => '9:00-10:00,12:00-15:00',
    'Sat' => '9:00-10:00,12:00-15:00',
    'Sun' => '10:00-14:00'
    );

$new_data = array();

foreach($data as $key => $value){
    $index = array_search($value, $new_data);
    if($index){
        $new_data[$index .'/' . $key] = $value;
        unset($new_data[$index]);
    }else{
        $new_data[$key] = $value;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($new_data);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

So, there my long example.

```
$date_array = Array(
    'Mon' => '9:00-10:00, 12:00-15:00, 10:00-14:00',
    'Tue' => '9:00-10:00, 12:00-15:00',
    'Wed' => '9:00-10:00, 12:00-15:00',
    'Thu' => '9:00-10:00, 12:00-15:00',
    'Fri' => '9:00-10:00, 12:00-15:00',
    'Sat' => '9:00-10:00, 12:00-15:00',
    'Sun' => '10:00-14:00',
);

$previous = null;
$new_days = array();
$new_times = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($date_array as $day => $time) {
    if ($time === $previous) {
        $new_days[$i] .= '/' . $day;
        $new_times[$i] = $time;
    } else {
        $i++;
        $new_days[$i] = $day;
        $new_times[$i] = $time;
    }
    $previous = $time;
}

var_dump(array_combine($new_days, $new_times));
```

Answer (score 0):

After re-viewing your question I came to the following solution, basically using `foreach` and using the value to aggregate days for as the key collecting the days (first foreach); then imploding the days into a single string (second foreach) and then flipping the array:

```
$output = array();

foreach ($input as $day => $time) $output[$time][] = $day;

foreach ($output as &$value) $value = implode('/', $value); 
unset ($value);

print_r(array_flip($output));
```

http://eval.in/14944